# how to get data from multiple tables in sql using php

Tags: php, sql, database

i have 4 tables in my db

(0)users

user id,user name,password

(1)messages

user id,user name(fk),message,location,time

(2) images

user name(fk),image id,image path,time

(3)videos
user name(fk),video id,video path,location,time

i want to show data from multiple tables

what will be query syntax  to do it
i want to show like
"rana " has upload this image and this video and this messages"

image  should be select from images table video from video tables and message from message table
thanks

sorry if question already asked 
thanks please help

Comment: read up on JOIN

Comment: can u give me link

Comment: I removed the DBMS specific tags because we have no idea which DBMS you are actually using. As for a link...have you tried google?

Comment: about you know php & mysql?

Comment: i am uning xampp server and sql

Comment: what you are already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected mysql query is :

```
select *from users a 
join messages b on a.user_name = b.user_name
join images c on a.user_name = c.user_name
join videos d on a.user_name = d.user_name
```

Example (MySQLi Procedural) & PHP

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "select *from users a 
join messages b on a.user_name = b.user_name
join images c on a.user_name = c.user_name
join videos d on a.user_name = d.user_name";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "User Name: " . $row["user_name"]. "<br />";
        echo "Message: " . $row["message"]. "<br />";
        echo "Image Path: " . $row["image_path"]. "<br />";
        echo "Video  Path: " . $row["video_path"]. "<br />";
        //you get more data as your wise................
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```